# ConcurrentHashMap why locking segments?

Tags: java

ConcurrentHashMap does optimization by locking the segments in place of locking the whole map. Wondering why can't it lock the key for better performance.

Comment: Two different key/value pairs could be stored in the same segment.

Comment: Also, two different objects with the same hash code can both serve as keys to the same entry, but locking one does not affect the other.

Comment: You should convert this to an answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that is only true if `.equals()` returns true, otherwise, they are 2 keys in the same segment.

Comment: In Java 8, that's roughly what it does; it doesn't use segments.

Comment: You are right, @Tezra, but my point is that it may be possible to access the same map entry via two or more distinct key objects.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't know synchronization policy for the key. Locking on the key can lead to unexpected behaviour and deadlocks because user code already held lock on the key.
2. You can treat segment like inner `HashMap` that serves only subset of hash codes. It need for effective access to the elements. So you should block access to the whole structure not only for one key. Otherwise you risk broke internal data structers due to non-synchronized modification.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, `Segment = HashCode`. `HashCodes` are not unique to each key (two different keys can have the same `HashCode`), and `HashMaps` store based on `HashCode`.

Now, you shouldn't worry too much about the implementation of that, but basically, each segment is the ***smallest unit of isolated space***, AKA, altering/removing/adding an item to a segment could affect other accesses to that segment.

So Segment is locked because that is the smallest ***space unit*** that is safe for all possible access cases.